How can I recompile main.scss after compiling of an imported sass file?
I have a main.scss file like as shown here:
@import 'test.scss';

After any changes in test.scss file, live sass compiler is compiling test.sass file correctly, but compile version of main.sass doesn't change, and I should recompile main.sass manually! Is there any config for automating this?
I using Live Sass Compiler in VS Code but I can't find any config for solving my problem

Sorry for the delay.
You currently have two choices:

You can rename the test file to start with an underscore.
Then the compiler will know the file is a partial and compile all other files (NOT including the test file itself)
or, you can tell the compiler extension that the test file is a partial file using the partialsList setting.
This will tell the compiler what your partial files are and then trigger compilation (add detailed in point 1)

